# Открытие клуба 200к. Поздравляем VladD

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, поздравление

Поздравляем Владислава, который первый на RuSO смог перешагнуть рубеж 100K -- [17.09.2016](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=32380198#32380198) и

первым открыл клуб 200к! -- [30.07.2021 г](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd?tab=reputation).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Впечатляющую статистику по количеству медалей по специальностям, количеству просмотров и ответов можно посмотреть в его [профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd?tab=reputation).
Но самое главное - это качество его ответов на протяжении всего долгого периода участия в жизни нашего сайта. Его ответы, это редкий сплав глубоких знаний  по затронутым вопросам в ответах и умение логично, доходчиво донести решение, хорошим, литературным языком.

Читая его ответы, невольно приходят на ум строчки из А.С. Пушкина

> И пальцы просятся к перу, перо к бумаге.
> Минута — и стихи свободно
> потекут.

Что можно пожелать,- оставаться на сайте, отвечать с удовольствием на вопросы, тем самым помогая людям.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям!

Comment: @VladD Класс! Поздравляю!

Comment: О, класс! Присоединяюсь! @VladD с достижением!

Comment: @VladD, поздравляю!

Comment: @VladD, красавчег, так держать!!!

Comment: Спасибо! Очень тронут!

Comment: Поздравляю! Блестящие ответы с разбором множества тонкостей - то, что является основой SO. Жаль, что владельцам/администрации этого уже не нужно..

Comment: @MBo Администрации не "не нужно", администрации всё равно. Выдали движок, поставили рамки копированием правил с enSO + немного странного рандома, а дальше - что хотите, то и делайте. Проблема скорее в том, что при таком подходе никаких серьезных изменений сделать нельзя, уровень сопротивления просто зашкаливает, и условная "демократия" свелась к "модерируйте контент по внешним правилам"

Comment: @VladD поздравляю с 200k %)

Answer (score 35):

Спасибо, друзья!

Что хочется сказать по этому поводу.

Во-первых, огромное спасибо за поздравления, очень тронут. Так уж сложилось, что я в последние несколько лет гораздо менее активен, чем в прошлом, и я рад, что эта веха не прошла незаметной.

Во-вторых, мне всегда приятно отвечать, и чтобы держать марку, мне пришлось в фоне выучить много интересных вещей, которые потом пригодились в профессии. На сайте всегда попадаются прекрасные вопросы, и вопросы, по которым есть что сказать за рамками общеизвестного. Ну и находить интересное и поучительное в казалось бы плохих вопросах — тоже прекрасная возможность прокачать и технические навыки, и умение объяснять, и в этом тоже есть своеобразная эстетика.

В-третьих, я многому научился, читая ответы других участников, которые разбираются во многом гораздо лучше меня (за что им отдельное спасибо).

В-четвёртых, я очень рад, что вопреки пессимистическим прогнозам (в том числе и моим), сайт растёт и на него приходят другие, новые, прекрасные отвечающие. Я уверен, что двери клуба 200K скоро примут многих других участников, и буду искренне рад видеть тех, кто обгонит меня.

---

Пользуясь случаем (tm), передаю привет и благодарность тем, кто в своё время поддерживал Кролика. Не буду перечислять всех поимённо, чтобы не дай бог никого не забыть и не обидеть.

Comment: 200k — это уже серьезно. Можно себе представить, сколько в них заложено времени, и сил конечно. Если имеется такая возможность, то так держать и дальше. Вторые и последующие первыми уже не будут. Первым может быть только один. И так сложилось, что это вы. Значит заслужено. Влад, успехов в достижении новых рекордов!

Comment: @Sevastopol': Спасибо! Я старался. Время, потраченное на поиски хороших формулировок, окупается применением этого в повседневной работе, так что я не в накладе.

Comment: Мои поздравления! С огромным удовольствием читаю Ваши ответы и периодически добавляю в заметки. Меня всегда интересовало откуда Вы берете столько времени для написания таких ответов. Я могу найти время и силы на десяток-другой более или менее качественных ответов, но то что делали и делаете Вы за гранью моего понимания. Это огромный труд и огромный вклад в сообщество. Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: Ждемс 300к от вас .

Comment: @МихаилРебров: Спасибо! Ну, сейчас уже времени поменьше получается, а так конечно много времени отнимало. Как-то на Мете меня подозревали в том, что на моём аккаунте сидит коллектив авторов :) — Пожалуйста, всегда рад, если то, что я написал, кому-то помогает!

Comment: @Randall: Ну это в далёком будущем, но спасибо, что верите в меня! 